# Can we get married in the consulate?

Tags: marriage, bangladeshi-citizens

I am non-EU citizen and my girlfriend  from Spain. I am Bangladesh national. Can we get married in the consulate of Spain in Bangladesh or have to try  somewhere (neighboring  countries) else?

Comment: Can you clarify why you'd want to get married in the consulate?

Comment: This will need to be found out at the embassy.  In Phillipines it won't be allowed: http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MANILA/en/ServiciosConsulares/Pages/Inscripciones-en-el-Registro-Civil-del-Consulado-General-de-Espa%C3%B1a-en-Manila.aspx

Comment: Why not get married in your city hall or whatever place would be normal for Bangladesh?

Comment: You can also get married wherever you want and after register the marriage in Spain (through the Consulate). Once the marriage is registered, the Spanish certificate will be valid all over Europe.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **MAYBE**

According to [Spanish Exterior Ministry](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MANILA/en/ServiciosConsulares/Pages/RegistroCivil.aspx) the conditions for consular marriage are:

> A consular marriage may only be held when at least one of the parties is Spanish and if the laws and regulations of the receiving state do not oppose consular marriages.

Since you're non-EU citizen the Spanish consulate will not perform the marriage unless Bangadesh recognizes consular marriage (for which I can't find confirmation).

Comment: +1 for the useful link and citation but doesn't your quote contradict your answer? “One of the parties” (namely the girlfriend) *is* a Spanish citizen.

Comment: Need sleep and re-read the question.

Comment: @DanieleDavì That should be a comment on the question rather then the answer.  But in some countries there is no marriage other than religious and there are restrictions on who can get married in the country.  I haven't checked but Bangladesh seem to me to be one of these.

Comment: @Karlson thanks a lot for the correction. I fixed. I basically answered to the second part of his question "(or have to try somewhere (neighboring countries) else?" which I think was important as well as the first part. Also considering what you are saying about marriage in some countries, consider to get married in a country where they after can get a proper recognized certificate could be the best option.